# How do I centre content in xaml when its resized?

Tags: wpf, xaml

How do I set grid columns in xaml to be center so that the elements on the screen always remain centered when the app is resized?

Comment: Use Width="*" instead of specificed value

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Column Definition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<TextBlock Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />

</Grid>
```